# Avoiding to evaluate expensive function in targetpenalty that already been evaluated in cost (mystic optimization package python)

Tags: python, optimization, mystic

I have an very expensive to evaluate function that needs to be computed in both the cost and targetpenalty in an optimization problem i am facing.
I was wondering if there is a workaround here?

Consider the code below highlighting the issue - this is just a toy example(thus the objective function is meant to be slow in this example)... the real getobjective2_ function is already optimized as far as it goes:

```
import numpy as np
from typing import List
import mystic
import pandas as pd
from mystic.symbolic import simplify
from mystic.symbolic import generate_constraint, generate_solvers
from mystic.monitors import VerboseMonitor, VerboseLoggingMonitor
from mystic.penalty import linear_inequality



def adstock_geometric(x: List, theta: float):
    x_decayed = np.zeros_like(x)
    x_decayed[0] = x[0]

    for xi in range(1, len(x_decayed)):
        x_decayed[xi] = x[xi] + theta * x_decayed[xi - 1]

    return x_decayed


def getobjective2_(x):

    for _ in range(100_000):
        pass
    adstocks = {'adstock-channel_1': np.array(0.08223851),
                'adstock-channel_2': np.array(0.28487006)}
    channels = ['channel_1', 'channel_2']
    horizon = 12
    coeffs = pd.DataFrame({'channel_2-saturationcoefficients': [0.73651 for _ in range(horizon)],
                           'timevar-channel_2': [0.27527, 0.14287, 0.12847, 0.02112,
                                                 0.03544, 0.05230, 0.21811, 0.27527,
                                                 0.14287, 0.12847, 0.02112, 0.03544],
                           'channel_1-saturationcoefficients': [0.70259 for _ in range(horizon)],
                           'timevar-channel_1': [0.13827, 0.24760, 0.28849,
                                                 0.33613, 0.34027, 0.28988,
                                                 0.21095, 0.13827, 0.24760,
                                                 0.28849, 0.33613, 0.34027]})

    incomingcostchannel_1 = np.array([0.10303531, 0.07283391, 0.14465764, 0.12315725, 0.07384496, 0.07709148,
                                      0.06425854, 0.09207129, 0.04114219, 0.04066119, 0.09510273, 0.06785441,
                                      0.08381945, 0.05025105, 0.0617348,  0.08135422, 0.04006317, 0.0348892,
                                      0.05374626, 0.05904413])
    incomingcoostchannel_2 = np.array([0.04199663, 0.05350016, 0.05427114, 0.05519786, 0.05449486, 0.05733955,
                                      0.0572036,  0.05479,    0.06165305, 0.06347637, 0.05837555, 0.05841943,
                                      0.05922741, 0.05826971, 0.05652555, 0.06605174, 0.0603985,  0.0617391,
                                      0.05811569, 0.05972648])

    def saturate(cost, channel):
        return np.power(cost, coeffs[f'{channel}-saturationcoefficients'].values)


    tbret = 0

    for idx, channel in enumerate(channels):
        try:
            adstockchannel = adstocks[f'adstock-{channel}']
        except KeyError:
            adstockchannel = 0.0

        costchannel = x[(idx * horizon): (idx * horizon) + horizon]

        if channel == "channel_1":
            incomingcost = incomingcostchannel_1
        else:
            incomingcost = incomingcoostchannel_2

        zerosoverhorizon = np.zeros(horizon)
        incomingcostoverhorizon = np.append(incomingcost, zerosoverhorizon)
        incomingcostoverhorizonadstocked = adstock_geometric(x=incomingcostoverhorizon,
                                                             theta=adstockchannel)[-horizon:]

        costchannel += incomingcostoverhorizonadstocked
        costadstocked = adstock_geometric(x=costchannel,
                                          theta=adstockchannel)
        costmediaprocessed = saturate(cost=costadstocked, channel=channel)

        costready = costmediaprocessed * coeffs[f'timevar-{channel}']

        tbret += sum(costready)

    return -tbret

def generatemysticconstraints(horizon, totalbudget, channels, minspendtotalconstraints,
                              maxjumps, maxcovers, totalbudgetconstraint=False):
    xs = [f"x{idx}" for idx in range(horizon * len(channels))]

    constraints = ""
    if totalbudgetconstraint:
        totalbudgetconstraint = f"{totalbudget} >= {'+'.join(xs)}"
        constraints += totalbudgetconstraint

    breakpoints = {channel: idx * horizon for idx, channel in enumerate(channels)}
    for channel, cutoff in breakpoints.items():
        fromx = cutoff
        tox = cutoff + horizon

        minspendchannel = minspendtotalconstraints[channel]

        maxjump = maxjumps[channel]
        maxcover = maxcovers[channel]

        minspendconstrainttotal = f"{'+'.join(xs[fromx: tox])} >= {minspendchannel}"
        constraints += '\n'
        constraints += minspendconstrainttotal

        for idx in range(fromx + 1, tox):
            maxjumpconstraint_ = f"({xs[idx - 1]} * {maxjump}) >= {xs[idx]}"
            constraints += '\n'
            constraints += maxjumpconstraint_

        for idx in range(fromx, tox - 1):
            maxcoverconstraint_ = f"({xs[idx + 1]} * {maxcover}) >= {xs[idx]}"
            constraints += '\n'
            constraints += maxcoverconstraint_
    return constraints

#
def run(totalbudget, targetvalue, scalefactor, scalefactorresponse,
        horizon, minspendtotalconstraints, channels, objective, strategy, maxjumps, maxcovers,
        x0, boundsextrapolation):

    totalbudget_ = totalbudget / scalefactor

    constraints = generatemysticconstraints(horizon=horizon,
                                            totalbudget=totalbudget_,
                                            channels=channels,
                                            minspendtotalconstraints=minspendtotalconstraints,
                                            maxjumps=maxjumps,
                                            maxcovers=maxcovers)
    def targetpenalty(x, target):
        if strategy == "targetroas":
            return target * (sum(x) * scalefactor) - (-objective(x) * scalefactorresponse)
        elif strategy == "targetcpa":
            return (sum(x) * scalefactor) - target * (-objective(x) * scalefactorresponse)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError

    def totalbudgetpenalty(x, totalbudget):
        return sum(x) - totalbudget

    @linear_inequality(condition=totalbudgetpenalty, kwds={'totalbudget': totalbudget_})
    @linear_inequality(condition=targetpenalty, kwds={'target': targetvalue})
    def penalty(x):
        return 0.0

    constraintsimplified = simplify(constraints,
                                    all=True)

    from mystic.constraints import and_

    generatedconstraints = generate_constraint(generate_solvers(constraintsimplified), join=and_)

    # stepmon = VerboseMonitor(1)
    stepmon = VerboseLoggingMonitor(1, 1)

    cost = lambda x: objective(x)

    bounds = boundsextrapolation
    print(f"starting configuration - totalbudget: {totalbudget}, targetvalue: {targetvalue}")
    optimum = mystic.solvers.diffev2(cost,
                                     x0=x0,
                                     constraints=generatedconstraints,
                                     bounds=bounds,
                                     penalty=penalty,
                                     full_output=True,
                                     stepmon=stepmon,
                                     itermon=stepmon,
                                     disp=True,
                                     tightrange=True,
                                     npop=40,
                                     # gtol=200,
                                     # maxfun=5000,
                                     maxiter=1000)

    optimalvalueslst = optimum[0]

    spend_channel_1 = optimalvalueslst[:horizon]
    spend_channel_2 = optimalvalueslst[horizon:]

    print(f"Percentage spent channel_1: {sum(spend_channel_1) / (sum(spend_channel_1) + sum(spend_channel_2))}")
    print(f"Percentage spent channel_2: {sum(spend_channel_2) / (sum(spend_channel_1) + sum(spend_channel_2))}")

    totalspent = np.sum(optimalvalueslst) * scalefactor

    sales = -objective(optimalvalueslst.copy()) * scalefactorresponse

    estimatedcpa = totalspent / sales
    estimatedroas = sales / totalspent

    penaltyvalue = targetvalue * sum(optimalvalueslst.copy()) - (-objective(optimalvalueslst.copy()))

    if totalspent > totalbudget * 1.02:
        # redo optimization
        raise ValueError("Spent more than totalbudget -> roas target too low / cpa target to high")

    print(f"total spent: {totalspent}")
    print(f"estimated cpa: {estimatedcpa}")
    print(f"estimated roas: {estimatedroas}")
    print(f"penalty value: {penaltyvalue}")

    return {'x': optimalvalueslst.copy(),
            'sales': sales,
            'estimatedroas': estimatedroas,
            'totalspent': totalspent,
            'totalbudget': totalbudget,
            'targetvalue': targetvalue
            }


def constraintverifier(solution, horizon, channels,
                       scalefactor, maxjumps, maxcovers,
                       minspendtotalconstraints, totalbudget, boundsextrapolation, targetmetric=False):
    breakpoints = {channel: idx * horizon for idx, channel in enumerate(channels)}

    if (sum(solution.copy()) * scalefactor) > totalbudget:
        return False

    if not targetmetric and abs((sum(solution.copy()) * scalefactor) - totalbudget) > totalbudget * 0.05:
        return False

    for channel, cutoff in breakpoints.items():
        fromx = cutoff
        tox = cutoff + horizon

        maxjump = maxjumps[channel]
        maxcover = maxcovers[channel]

        minspendchannel = minspendtotalconstraints[channel]

        solchannel = solution[fromx: tox].copy()

        boundschannel = boundsextrapolation[fromx: tox]

        if not all(lb <= x <= ub for x, (lb, ub) in zip(solchannel.copy(), boundschannel)):
            return False

        if sum(solchannel.copy()) * scalefactor < minspendchannel:
            return False

        lastvalue = solchannel[0]

        for sequentvalue in solchannel[1:].copy():
            if ((lastvalue * maxjump) * 1.01) < sequentvalue:  # multiplication by 1.01 due to rounding errors
                return False
            if (lastvalue * 1.01) < sequentvalue * (1 / maxcover):  # multiplication by 1.01 due to rounding errors
                return False
            lastvalue = sequentvalue
    return True


def getdefaulttestvalues():
    scalefactor = 11621.64675797
    scalefactorresponse = 118257.501641172

    horizon = 12

    minspendtotalconstraints = {'channel_2': 0.0,
                                'channel_1': 0.0}

    targetvalue = 3.0  # vs 2.5

    channels = ['channel_1', 'channel_2']

    objective = getobjective2_

    strategy = "targetroas"

    maxjumps = {'channel_1': 2.5,
                'channel_2': 1.5}
    maxcovers = {'channel_1': 2.5,
                 'channel_2': 1.5}

    x0 = [0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407,
          0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407,
          0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407,
          0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407,
          0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407,
          0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407, 0.017209265103744407]

    boundsextrapolation = [(0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933), (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933), (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933), (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933), (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933), (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933), (0.014964578351082093, 5.602713613312933),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604), (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604), (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604), (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604), (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604), (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604),
                           (0.014964578351082093, 1.158821015684604)]
    return scalefactor, scalefactorresponse, horizon, \
           minspendtotalconstraints, targetvalue, channels, \
           objective, strategy, maxjumps, maxcovers, x0, boundsextrapolation


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from collections import defaultdict
    def tree():
        return defaultdict(tree)

    scalefactor, scalefactorresponse, horizon, \
    minspendtotalconstraints, targetvalue, channels, \
    objective, strategy, maxjumps, maxcovers, x0, boundsextrapolation = getdefaulttestvalues()

    results = tree()
    total_budgets = [50_000, 200_000, 250_000, 500_000]
    targetvals = [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 10.0]
    for totbud in total_budgets:
        for targetval in targetvals:
            res2 = run(totalbudget=totbud, targetvalue=targetval,
                       horizon=horizon, channels=channels,
                       scalefactor=scalefactor, maxjumps=maxjumps,
                       maxcovers=maxcovers, minspendtotalconstraints=minspendtotalconstraints,
                       boundsextrapolation=boundsextrapolation, objective=getobjective2_,
                       x0=x0, strategy=strategy,
                       scalefactorresponse=scalefactorresponse)

    print(results)
```

We are evaluating the objective function in both the targetpenalty and cost which i would really like to avoid(a single evaluation would speed up things alot), is there a workaround here?

Some ideas is to use parallelized computing utilizing e.g pathos,but i couldnt find any examples of doing so with diffev2, i will also try to reduce the number of workers but i found out that i get stuck in local optimas quite fast.. i found that the optimizer works well for all my datasets if i have around 50 workers..any ideas on how to speed this up?

***EDIT*** code updated to allow for caching

```
def run(totalbudget, targetvalue, scalefactor, scalefactorresponse,
        horizon, minspendtotalconstraints, channels, objective, strategy, maxjumps, maxcovers,
        x0, boundsextrapolation):

    totalbudget_ = totalbudget / scalefactor

    constraints = generatemysticconstraints(horizon=horizon,
                                            totalbudget=totalbudget_,
                                            channels=channels,
                                            minspendtotalconstraints=minspendtotalconstraints,
                                            maxjumps=maxjumps,
                                            maxcovers=maxcovers)
    import mystic.cache as mc
    a = mc.archive.read('cache.db', type=mc.archive.file_archive)
    objectivecached = mc.cached(archive=a)(objective)

    def targetpenalty(x, target):
        if strategy == "targetroas":
            return target * (sum(x) * scalefactor) - (-objectivecached(x) * scalefactorresponse)
        elif strategy == "targetcpa":
            return (sum(x) * scalefactor) - target * (-objectivecached(x) * scalefactorresponse)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError

    def totalbudgetpenalty(x, totalbudget):
        return sum(x) - totalbudget

    @linear_inequality(condition=totalbudgetpenalty, kwds={'totalbudget': totalbudget_})
    @linear_inequality(condition=targetpenalty, kwds={'target': targetvalue})
    def penalty(x):
        return 0.0

    constraintsimplified = simplify(constraints,
                                    all=True)

    from mystic.constraints import and_

    generatedconstraints = generate_constraint(generate_solvers(constraintsimplified), join=and_)

    # stepmon = VerboseMonitor(1)
    stepmon = VerboseLoggingMonitor(1, 1)

    cost = lambda x: objectivecached(x)

    bounds = boundsextrapolation
    print(f"starting configuration - totalbudget: {totalbudget}, targetvalue: {targetvalue}")
    optimum = mystic.solvers.diffev2(cost,
                                     x0=x0,
                                     constraints=generatedconstraints,
                                     bounds=bounds,
                                     penalty=penalty,
                                     full_output=True,
                                     stepmon=stepmon,
                                     itermon=stepmon,
                                     disp=True,
                                     tightrange=True,
                                     npop=40,
                                     # gtol=200,
                                     # maxfun=5000,
                                     maxiter=1000)

    optimalvalueslst = optimum[0]

    spend_channel_1 = optimalvalueslst[:horizon]
    spend_channel_2 = optimalvalueslst[horizon:]

    print(f"Percentage spent channel_1: {sum(spend_channel_1) / (sum(spend_channel_1) + sum(spend_channel_2))}")
    print(f"Percentage spent channel_2: {sum(spend_channel_2) / (sum(spend_channel_1) + sum(spend_channel_2))}")

    totalspent = np.sum(optimalvalueslst) * scalefactor

    sales = -objective(optimalvalueslst.copy()) * scalefactorresponse

    estimatedcpa = totalspent / sales
    estimatedroas = sales / totalspent

    penaltyvalue = targetvalue * sum(optimalvalueslst.copy()) - (-objective(optimalvalueslst.copy()))

    if totalspent > totalbudget * 1.02:
        # redo optimization
        raise ValueError("Spent more than totalbudget -> roas target too low / cpa target to high")

    print(f"total spent: {totalspent}")
    print(f"estimated cpa: {estimatedcpa}")
    print(f"estimated roas: {estimatedroas}")
    print(f"penalty value: {penaltyvalue}")

    return {'x': optimalvalueslst.copy(),
            'sales': sales,
            'estimatedroas': estimatedroas,
            'totalspent': totalspent,
            'totalbudget': totalbudget,
            'targetvalue': targetvalue
            }
```

Comment: I'm the mystic author. The workaround that I generally use for super expensive objectives involves using a mystic.cache to cache the objective.  Then the penalty function does a lookup on the cache instead of reevaluating the objective.  The penalty is always evaluated after the cost, so a caching the objective works.

Comment: Lovely, precisely what i was looking for! would have accepted it as an full answer. Thanks, and btw, awesome package you created!

Comment: BTW, I'm also the `pathos` author.  If you are looking for an example of how to run `diffev2` with `pathos`, you need to use the `map` keyword, and you should pass a `pathos` `Map` instance.  I can point you to one or edit answer if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment... we create an expensive function

```
>>> def expensive(x):
...   import time
...   time.sleep(.01)
...   return sum(x)
... 
>>> import mystic as my
>>> import mystic.cache as mc
>>> import mystic.penalty as mp
```

Now create a standard file archive that captures function input and output, and retains calling order.

We generate a function that writes to the archive, where it uses function input as the key, and function output as the value and is ordered by function call.

```
>>> a = mc.archive.read('cache.db', type=mc.archive.file_archive)
>>> objective = mc.cached(archive=a)(expensive)
```

Set some bounds

```
>>> xlb = (0,1,0,0,0)
>>> xub = (1,10,10,10,10)
>>> bounds = list(zip(xlb, xub))
```

Create a penalty (where the objective is used)

```
>>> mon = my.monitors.Monitor()
>>> @mp.quadratic_inequality(condition=lambda x: (2 - objective(x)**2))
... def penalty(x):
...   return 0.0
... 
>>> penalty([0,0,0,1,0])
200.0
>>> penalty([1,1,1,1,1])
0.0
```

Optimize, using a evaluation monitor

```
>>> res = my.solvers.fmin(objective, x0=xlb, bounds=bounds, evalmon=mon, full_output=True, disp=False, penalty=penalty)
>>> 
>>> x,y = res[:2]
>>> assert objective(x) + penalty(x) == y
```

Archived rv and cost should match evaluation monitor, regardless of size (to look up the last entry, we need to use keys(), so we just check all keys). The file archives preserve order, but we convert to nested lists to compare.

```
>>> xs,ys = list(list(k) for k in a.keys()), list(a.values())
>>> assert xs == mon.x
>>> assert ys == mon.y
```

Remove the archive

```
>>> import os
>>> os.remove('cache.db')
```

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the code(see the below EDIT part), too my surprise it got a lot slower using caching, i must have missed something vital in the code but i cant find it or is it that in this case the objective function is not sufficiently slow for an speed increase using caching?

Comment: Yes, that's possible as the cache has file IO. You could try caching to memory with a `dict_archive`... and if that's slower than, yeah, it's better to just re-evaluate the objective.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you might do is switch the guts out from `pandas` data frame to good old dictionaries.  Making a new data frame every time the function is called is *expensive*.  I tried this and got a pretty decent speed boost.  There's probably more to do...

```
def getobjective2_(x):

    adstocks = {'adstock-channel_1': np.array(0.08223851),
                'adstock-channel_2': np.array(0.28487006)}
    channels = ['channel_1', 'channel_2']
    horizon = 12
    coeffs = {'channel_1':{'saturationcoefficients': [0.73651 for _ in range(horizon)],
                           'timevar': [0.27527, 0.14287, 0.12847, 0.02112,
                                                 0.03544, 0.05230, 0.21811, 0.27527,
                                                 0.14287, 0.12847, 0.02112, 0.03544],},
              'channel_2':{ 'saturationcoefficients': [0.70259 for _ in range(horizon)],
                           'timevar': [0.13827, 0.24760, 0.28849,
                                                 0.33613, 0.34027, 0.28988,
                                                 0.21095, 0.13827, 0.24760,
                                                 0.28849, 0.33613, 0.34027]}}

    incomingcostchannel_1 = np.array([0.10303531, 0.07283391, 0.14465764, 0.12315725, 0.07384496, 0.07709148,
                                      0.06425854, 0.09207129, 0.04114219, 0.04066119, 0.09510273, 0.06785441,
                                      0.08381945, 0.05025105, 0.0617348,  0.08135422, 0.04006317, 0.0348892,
                                      0.05374626, 0.05904413])
    incomingcoostchannel_2 = np.array([0.04199663, 0.05350016, 0.05427114, 0.05519786, 0.05449486, 0.05733955,
                                      0.0572036,  0.05479,    0.06165305, 0.06347637, 0.05837555, 0.05841943,
                                      0.05922741, 0.05826971, 0.05652555, 0.06605174, 0.0603985,  0.0617391,
                                      0.05811569, 0.05972648])

    def saturate(cost, channel):
        return np.power(cost, coeffs[channel]['saturationcoefficients'])


    tbret = 0

    for idx, channel in enumerate(channels):
        try:
            adstockchannel = adstocks[f'adstock-{channel}']
        except KeyError:
            adstockchannel = 0.0

        costchannel = x[(idx * horizon): (idx * horizon) + horizon]

        if channel == "channel_1":
            incomingcost = incomingcostchannel_1
        else:
            incomingcost = incomingcoostchannel_2

        zerosoverhorizon = np.zeros(horizon)
        incomingcostoverhorizon = np.append(incomingcost, zerosoverhorizon)
        incomingcostoverhorizonadstocked = adstock_geometric(x=incomingcostoverhorizon,
                                                             theta=adstockchannel)[-horizon:]

        costchannel += incomingcostoverhorizonadstocked
        costadstocked = adstock_geometric(x=costchannel,
                                          theta=adstockchannel)
        costmediaprocessed = saturate(cost=costadstocked, channel=channel)

        costready = costmediaprocessed * coeffs[channel]['timevar']

        tbret += sum(costready)

    return -tbret
```

Comment: this is just a toy example(thus the objective function is meant to be slow in this example)... the real objective function is already optimized as far as it goes. Will add this info more explicitly to the description.